# Updating the value of variable in a java script to html

Tags: javascript, html, variables, html5-canvas

I am using canvas 3d to draw a 3d graph.So i am using java script for rotation and keypress event and so on. It works fine also.But i want to print the angle by which i have rotated the surface. I do have variable in java script which stores this value.
Now my question is how can i print the value of variable  in a html body so that when i rotate the surface of canvas the value keeps on updating? If i can't do that atleast  tell me the method by which i can display the value on some button click or any event.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a update function like this:

```
function update(){
   document.querySelector("#log").innerHTML = angle;
}
```

and call that function every time you modify your value (the `click` event of course is only for demonstration purposes):

```
document.querySelector("#square").addEventListener("click",function(){
   this.style["-webkit-transform"] = "rotate("+(angle+=10)+"deg)";
    update();
});
```

see the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LnM4C/5/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `setInterval(function, time)`, it call a function repeated times, with `time` milliseconds between the execution.

```
setInterval(function() {
    [Code That Update Your Value]
}, 100);
```

Comment: setting an Interval would be redundant, a callback function is more suitable here.

Comment: I agree with you, but we don't know how is the librarie that @Navaneet is using, `click` seems not be the right to listener, but if was, your answer is best

Comment: that click event was only exemplary for any arbitrary event. The big advantage of a callback is that it triggers when you need it and not in some fixed interval. Imagine the keypress comes far more often or perhaps not at all.

Comment: Of course, @Navaneet needs to know which event to attach the listener, this way your solution is best, if doesn't know about that, my solution solve his problem for a while

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps, you could install [`Firebug`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) and use console.log(), console.debug() without adding new elements. I think that would be useful for other projects as well. [Documentation link](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Message_types)